# Display a message box when vlookup returns or does not return a match

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display a message box* indicating when a vlookup formula matches a name in an array and when it does not.

With the below data, my current code works fine:

```
Name Name
John John
```

It returns the following message box: "Ok"

```
Sub check_name()
Dim name As String
name = Range("A2")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A2"), Range("B1:B2"), 1, False) = name Then
    MsgBox "Ok"
Else
    MsgBox "Not Ok"

End If
End Sub
```

But the code does not work when there is not a match.
With the below data, I'm trying to display: "Not Ok".

```
Name Name
John Wayne
```

I get the following message:

> Run-time error '1004'
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

I guess the `If` statement does not work when the `vlookup` does not return a match, i.e, if the formula returns `#N/A` (not available).

<sub>I've tried to define the variable `name` as Boolean. making it equal the vlookup formula wrapped with `IsNA`, and then I tried to use 'name' inside an If statement, but I got the same pattern of results presented above.</sub>

How I can get through this? Tks.

* <sub>Looking for answers using VBA</sub>

Comment: Try simply: `MsgBox IIF(IsError(Application.Match(name, Range("B1:B2"), False)), "Not OK", "OK")`.

Comment: Gahhh. there's an accepted answer for a similar question as indicated for the Close reason, but it's not really that good of an answer... I was about 5 seconds away from submitting my answer when this question was marked as officially "closed". If you want to PM/chat me or send me an email (dzemens@gmail.com) I can give you my full answer.  Cheers.

Comment: @DavidZemens Its Doug's answer from the duplicate which should be used. Agree the accepted one isn't smooth.

Comment: Yes @brettdj Doug's is the best answer there. Next time I will try to be faster...  my answer explained why that approach is preferably to the `On Error Resume Next` and also explains the terniary `IIF` statement I mentioned above :)

Comment: Basically the difference between `Application.Vlookup` and `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` is that the former will return an error-value when the match isn't found, and the latter will *raise an error* that stops code execution.  So, use the `Application.Vlookup` (or `Application.Match` would also work) to test for error and handle accordingly.

Comment: Great point @DavidZemens. Even though in most cases, these are used interchangeably, and the performance of `Worksheetfunction.` is much better, this is one of those not-as-well-known differences between the two.

Comment: The comment I posted initially uses the `Application.Match` function (analogous to a single-column Vlookup) inside an `IIF` ([immediate If](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) function).  It basically consolidates an `If/Then` to a single-line function.

Comment: @DavidZemens, I tested your approach inside a ForEach Loop (as I have lots of rows) and it worked perfectly. Do you know if is possible to exit the loop using this approach the first time I get a "Not Ok" message?

Comment: Declare a string variable: `Dim msg$`. Assign the result of the IIF function to that variable:  `msg = IIF(IsError(Application.Match(name, Range("B1:B2"), False)), "Not OK", "OK")`, then display the message: `msgBox msg`, finally a simple boolean test on the value of that string to conditionally exit: `If msg = "Not OK" Then Exit For`.

Comment: ALternatively just use normal `If/Then` conditional block. The `IIF` is really meant to be inline evaluation so it's not best suited for then dealing with additional instructions based on the returned value.

Comment: @DavidZemens please feel free to comment on (or even edit) my answer in that other question, and I'll incorporate (or appreciate) it.

Comment: @DougGlancy done! I left out some lengthy examples of error handling but otherwise added to your existing answer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidZemens, looks good! I left a comment noting your additions.

Comment: @DougGlancy Excellent. Much better that the existing answer is slightly updated as the master reference rather than a new version here is answered again. Particularly as your answer is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with simply declaring `Validation rules` for the cells under question.

You need to select `Validation` and then choose to validate the cells from a list (another range that contains the cells you need).

If you absolutely need to do it in VBA, you'll have to do some Error trapping.

Basically you need to add the code:

```
Function ThisFunction()
    On Error GoTo  ErrorHandler

    ' Your normal code
    ' The next two lines are VERY IMPORTANT. If you don't Exit, you'll get weird logical errors on runtime
    ThisFunction = '...
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
' Code to return the results in case of Error
ThisFunction = '...
End Function
```

The error arises on `No Match` results and that cannot be handled directly by the `WorksheetFunction.VLookup()`

This code, specifically is to be modified as

```
    Sub check_name()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim name As String
    name = Range("A2")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A2"), Range("B1:B2"), 1, False) = name Then
        MsgBox "Ok"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Ok" ' Never invoked
    End If
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Not ok"
End Sub
```

This is a very inefficient way of accomplishing this task, but this is the least modified approach to the problem so it will fit in with the rest of your code in this Subroutine

Comment: haha, no problem, i'll do it whenever i'm near a computer, usually i type these things from a phone or tablet, so it's tough to handle formatting and stuff and I keep it to the bare minimum which'll help the question. But point noted.